# Why was Tyrion shown in the background?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Spoilers from the Season 7 finale of Game of Thrones, "The Dragon and the Wolf":

> Tyrion in shown in the background when Jon enters Dany's room while sailing back to Winterfell. Why so? Are they trying to imply that he loved her as well?

Comment: Duplicate: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79608/why-did-tyrion-look-displeased

Comment: Another duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/168244/what-is-the-significance-of-tyrion-watching-this-door

Comment: Tyrion knows that they are related